# FullCalendar v5.10.1 using custom month and day names in locales

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using *FullCalendar v5.10.1* and in the locales file that I'm using the months are translated by default, but they are not with capital letters (I'm using the bg.js locales file):

```
  'use strict';

  var bg = {
    code: 'bg',
    week: {
      dow: 1, // Monday is the first day of the week.
      doy: 7, // The week that contains Jan 1st is the first week of the year.
    },
    buttonText: {
      prev: 'Назад',
      next: 'Напред',
      today: 'Днес',
      month: 'Месец',
      week: 'Седмица',
      day: 'Ден',
      list: 'График',
    },
    allDayText: 'Цял ден',
    moreLinkText: function(n) {
      return '+още ' + n
    },
    noEventsText: 'Няма събития за показване',
  };

  return bg;

}());
```

**Can I use some kind of an array for monthNames** or for an example (what is the integrated property for months?):

```
monthNames: {
   1: 'Януари', //for January
   2: 'Февруари', //for February
   ...
}
```

**or is there any other workaround for a custom months translation?**

Comment: `Can I use some kind of an array for monthNames`...no. As per the documentation, fullCalendar uses the names provided (or, in some cases not provided!) by the JavaScript Date implementation in your browser. Not all locales are supported by every browser, so what you see may vary from browser to browser. You may be able to find a polyfill for your locale online for the JS Date implementation - this is not related to fullcalendar

Comment: I found out there are some locales definitions at moment.js locales files so I changed them as well: var bg = moment.defineLocale('bg', {
        months: 'Януари_Февруари_Март_Април_Май_Юни_Юли_Август_Септември_Октомври_Ноември_Декември'.split(
            '_'
        ), and included all scripts : <script src="~/plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/moment/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/moment/locales.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/moment/locale/bg.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>, but this doesn't change anything too.

Comment: And did you set fullCalendar to start using the momentJS plugin?

Comment: I added the plugin as is written in the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment-plugin. I've added https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/moment@5.5.0/main.global.min.js (but I downloaded it locally) and formated the date: var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  titleFormat: ' D MMMM YYYY' 
}) aaand.... it worked finally - now I have months with the desired translation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, thanks to @ADyson I got to the solution.
I needed to change locales definitions at moment.js locales files:

```
var bg = moment.defineLocale('bg', { months: 'Януари_Февруари_Март_Април_Май_Юни_Юли_Август_Септември_Октомври_Ноември_Декември'.split( '_' )
```

then I included all needed scripts with custom translations:

```
<script src="~/plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script> 
<script src="~/plugins/moment/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script> 
<script src="~/plugins/moment/locales.js"></script> 
<script src="~/plugins/moment/locale/bg.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

At last I added the moment plugin as is written in the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment-plugin.
I've added:

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/moment@5.5.0/main.global.min.js'></script>
```

(but I downloaded it locally)
and then formated the date:

> var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
> titleFormat: 'D MMMM YYYY'
> })

and it worked - now I have months with the desired translation :)

Comment: Does anyone know if Luxon.js supports defining a custom locale? I would like to implement Latin in some of my projects, but alas the Unicode consortium does not yet support the "la" locale. So I need to custom define it...